# $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+2}$ without using the definition of $e$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove the following inequality, without using the definition of $e$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+2}
\end{equation}
$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: may be induction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram-Alpha 
[yields the result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk+%3D+0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D1%2Fk%21)
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}
=
{{\rm e}\,\Gamma\left(n+1, 1\right) \over n!}
$$